# Angular : changing setinterval timer via range slider

Tags: angular, setinterval, ionic4, ion-range-slider

l am using ionic 4 and angular . l want to use [ionic range slider](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/range) . The range slider lets users to change a range of values by moving the slider . l want to change the value of setInterval to reduce refresh or increase speed of refreshing .

My code

```
  time : 600 ;
  speed = 300;
  private interval;

rangeChanged(){
    this.speed = 300 * this.time;

    console.log(this.time)
  }


  play() {

    this.interval = setInterval(() => {

   // i deleted my code here 

    }, this.time);
  }
```

The problem is ,  `this.time` in `rangeChanged` function is not getting update 
 . When l changing the range slider the values `setInterval` are still same ! are not updating , in that case i have to stop `setInterval` then start again even he get new values . My point is how can make it live updating value for `setInterval` speed ?

html

```
<ion-range min="300" max="600" [(ngModel)]="time" color="secondary"
   (ngModelChange)="rangeChanged($event)" step="10" debounce="500">
    <ion-label range-left>3</ion-label>
    <ion-label range-right>10</ion-label>
  </ion-range>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method setInterval is already invoked when you called method play() with this.time value at that time.

If you want to change any other value inside the callback method ie the first argument of setinterval you can hook it up with some getter methods, But if you want to change the interval you have to clear and call again

```
rangeChanged(e){
  this.speed = 300 * e;

  console.log(e.target.value)
  play(e)
}

play(time) {
  if(this.interval) {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }

  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    const r = getAnotherValue(); // will work
  }, time);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering . but still values of setinterval are not change

Comment: which values dont change?

Comment: interval of `setInterval` .

Comment: did you call this `play(this.time)`

Comment: it is changed only if stop `setInterval` then play again

Comment: you mean that this.time in rangeChanged function is not getting updated?

Comment: yes your right that what i mean this.time in rangeChanged function is not getting update

Comment: than it is a different problem, not this one

Comment: try putting an argument in rangechanged, you are passing $event so you can get the updated value from there, maybe the this.time is not updating right away

Comment: see the updated code. if the `e.target.value` doesn't work try `e.target.data`

Comment: error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Comment: when i use `console.log(e)` l got number values change

Comment: did you find the time value?

Comment: ya so plug it in play(e)

Comment: okay now when l click on range slider line the value time is changing . but if i click on play button and change range slider the value time doesn't change

Comment: can we go to discussion to chat?